# Error on variable declaration in C

Tags: c, variables, declaration

I'm having some trouble with a variable declaration in C which I hope you can help me with.

This code:

```
int makeDir(const char* path, mode_t mode) {
    printf("Checkpoint 1\n");
    String parentPath;
    printf("Checkpoint 2\n");
    pDirTreeNode parent;
    printf("Checkpoint 3\n");
    int idx, grp;
    pinode inod;
    pdir algo=NULL;
    printf("Checkpoint 4\n");
    pdir direntry=NULL;
    printf("Checkpoint 5\n");
    t_bitarray *bitarr;

    parent = malloc(sizeof(struct dirTreeNode));
    parentPath = malloc(DIR_NAME_SIZE);
    direntry=malloc(sizeof(struct s_direct));

    [COMMENTED code]
}
```

And these are the data type declarations:

```
typedef struct s_inode      *pinode;    
typedef struct s_direct     *pdir;      
typedef char                *String;    
typedef struct dirTreeNode  *pDirTreeNode;
```

with s_inode and s_direct being declared in linux/ext2_fs.h header

I've executed it  and when the program reaches the function it prompts:

Stopped due to shared library event
/build/buildd/gdb-7.3/gdb/dwarf2loc.c:185: internal-error: dwarf_expr_frame_base: Assertion `framefunc != NULL' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.

But it doesn't stops the debug session. Then, if I execute the rest of the code:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000a5cdf0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a6e6)[0x7fa21d6e26e6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7d3e7)[0x7fa21d6e53e7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0xf9)[0x7fa21d6e6b39]
/home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev[0x402cd3]
/home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev[0x4017a4]
/home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev[0x400af7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fa21d68930d]
/home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev[0x4009e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 540784                             /home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev
00603000-00604000 r--p 00003000 00:14 540784                             /home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 00:14 540784                             /home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev
00a5c000-00a7d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fa214000000-7fa214021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa214021000-7fa218000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa21b706000-7fa21b71b000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 526333                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa21b71b000-7fa21b91a000 ---p 00015000 08:16 526333                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa21b91a000-7fa21b91b000 r--p 00014000 08:16 526333                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa21b91b000-7fa21b91c000 rw-p 00015000 08:16 526333                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa21b91c000-7fa21d668000 rw-p 00000000 00:14 273074                     /home/vlad/Sistemas Operativos/ext2.disk
7fa21d668000-7fa21d7ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 526221                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7fa21d7ff000-7fa21d9fe000 ---p 00197000 08:16 526221                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7fa21d9fe000-7fa21da02000 r--p 00196000 08:16 526221                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7fa21da02000-7fa21da03000 rw-p 0019a000 08:16 526221                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7fa21da03000-7fa21da09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa21da09000-7fa21da2a000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 523159                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7fa21dc10000-7fa21dc13000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa21dc26000-7fa21dc29000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa21dc29000-7fa21dc2a000 r--p 00020000 08:16 523159                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7fa21dc2a000-7fa21dc2c000 rw-p 00021000 08:16 523159                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7fff21b19000-7fff21b3a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff21ba2000-7fff21ba3000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 3
Checkpoint 4
Checkpoint 5
```

In a debug session, the code is actually exploding just after perror("1"), so it seems is not just a perror's problem...

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I've changed the dump messages and the function's code to avoid perrors. Also, this is the full main code:

```
pext2fs fsys; // Variable global

int main(int argv, char *argc[]) {
    fsys = malloc(sizeof(struct ext2system));

    getsysdata();

    /*                                              *
     *                                              *
     *                                              *
     * File System Client here                      *
     *                                              *
     *                                              *
     *                                              */

    /* ------------------>Código para probar funciones<------------------ */

    pDirTreeNode node;
    StringArray test;
    void **file=malloc(0);
    int ctrl, mode=0x1000;
    pdir *dirents;

    makeDir("\\Dir2\\DirCreadoInternamente", mode);
    node = getDirTreeNode("\\Dir2\\DirCreadoInternamente");
    //  dirents = list_dir(fsys->root);
    //  node = getDirTreeNode("\\Dir3\\UnDir");
    //  ctrl = getFile(&file, "\\Dir1\\LPD");
    //  printFile(file);

    /* ------------------>Fin del código de testing<------------------ */

    unmap(fsys->diskmap);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The definition `typedef char *String;` is a bad idea. A *string*, in C, is a sequence of characters; a pointer is not a string, but can be used to manipulate strings. Just use `char*` directly.

Comment: I was using a malloc on that string, but I moved it down to test whether it was the malloc or the declaration which was failing.

Comment: Many people, including myself, disagree with Keith's opinion.

Comment: @JimBalter, I don't see what in Keith' comment is an opinion.

Comment: @JensGustedt All normative assertions are opinions. Perhaps you overlooked the words "bad idea".

Comment: @JimBalter: Because the code used `String`, I was unable to understand it without finding and reading the definition of `String` (which, in real life, might be buried in some obscure header). If it had used `char*`, I would have understood the declaration immediately. Furthermore, using the name `String` reinforces the misconception that strings are pointers.

Comment: @Keith yes, C has headers and typedefs. Welcome to C.

Comment: @JimBalter: Headers and typedefs can be misused. Typedefs for pointer types are usually a bad idea; see, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/827263. (Thanks for the welcome, but I've been using C for about 30 years.)

Comment: The welcome is a direct response to your complaint. Also, you've moved the goalposts from "String is a bad idea" (which, again, I disagree with) to the ability to read code snippets, which is frankly a silly complaint. And now you broaden your opinion to *all* typedefs for pointer types, which even more people disagree with. I've written in C for 35 years and have seen a lot of idiosyncratic preferences passed off as fact -- the longer term programmers seem more prone to them (I do it occasionally myself). End of discussion for me; have a nice day.

Comment: Just a bit more: I myself have used String typedefs but not ptype typedefs as the latter achieve nothing but change '*' to 'p' and move it around. But it's a matter of choice. And also, anything at all can be misused; that is not an HONEST complaint; it is not part of an HONEST exchange. Good day.

Answer (score 2):

The `perror()` function prints an error message that depends on the current value of `errno`. It makes sense to call it *only* after calling a function that sets `errno`.

For example:

```
String parentPath;
perror("2");
```

You haven't done anything that would set `errno` to a meaningful value, so you're getting garbage. (`errno` was probably set to `EINVAL` as a side effect of the previous call to `perror()`).

The value of `errno` tells you *which* error occurred. Before checking it (either by examining `errno` or calling `perror()`), you should first determine *whether* an error occurred. Most functions that set `errno` also return a value that indicates success or failure. For example, `malloc()` returns a null pointer when it fails.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for the answer.
I wrote those perrors because the program **is** actually exploding when I reach that point on a debug session. In fact, the session ended without reaching the perror sentence, it's only running the program that I get that output. Any hint? 

(btw, I appreciate this answer that you gave me, it's useful even not solving the original prob (: )

Comment: Sorry, I didn't knew what you just explained so I thought it was clear that it was something wrong just before perror("2") execution.
Well, that's the problem then.

(Really, sorry guys :/ )

Comment: @Vladimir: The useless `perror` calls are obscuring tbe problem. The place where you say it's blowing up simply declares a `char*` object; there's no way that should cause such a problem. Show us code, preferably a self-contained program, without the `perror` calla, and tell us *exactly* where and how it fails (without using the word "explodes" unless it literally explodes).

Comment: I've edited the question, it's all there now.
Ok, it doesn't explodes, it just suddenly stops the execution and prompts a dump :P

Answer (score 1):

Various library functions may set `errno` to arbitrary values, but *unless they return an error value, no error has actually occurred*, and you should **not** trust `errno` otherwise.